# celery worker only work once

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, worker

full steps:

1. start django
2. start a celery worker

   python manage.py celery worker --app=celery_worker:app -Ofair -n W1
3. upload a url list file, loop url list send each url to a task `fetch_article`
4. worker works
5. upload another url list file
6. worker no actions

views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def upload(request):

    job_name = request.POST.get('job_name')
    if not job_name:
        return JsonResponse(JsonStatus.Error)

    if len(request.FILES) == 1:
        yq_data = request.FILES.values()[0]
    else:
        return JsonResponse(JsonStatus.Error)

    job = Job.objects.create(name=job_name)

    reader = csv.reader(yq_data, delimiter=',')

    task_count = 0

    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        url = row[0].strip()
        fetch_article.delay(job.id, url)
        # fetch_article.apply_async(args=[job.id, url], queue=job.queue_name)
        task_count += 1


    # print 'qn%s' % job.queue_name
    # rp = celery_app.control.add_consumer(queue=job.queue_name, reply=True)
    # print rp

    job.task_count = task_count
    job.save()

    return JsonResponse(JsonStatus.OK, msg=task_count)
```

tasks.py

```
@shared_task()
def fetch_article(job_id, url):

    logger.info(u'fetch_article:%s' % url)

    Processer = get_processor_cls(url)

    a = Article(job_id=job_id, url=url)
    try:
        ap = Processer(url)
        title, text = ap.process()
        a.title = title
        a.content = text

    except Exception as e:
        a.status = 2
        a.error = e
        logger.error(u'fetch_article:%s error:%s' % (url, e))

    a.save()
```

Comment: how many workers are spawned? can you add some excerpts from the celery logs? what do the various `celery inspect` commands show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,  I found the problem.

Because I set `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` in settings.
The task run in django main process, so worker no actions

from doc:

> CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER If this is True, all tasks will be executed
>   locally by blocking until the task returns. apply_async() and
>   Task.delay() will return an EagerResult instance, which emulates the
>   API and behavior of AsyncResult, except the result is already
>   evaluated.
>
> That is, tasks will be executed locally instead of being sent to the
>   queue.

For the worker work first time, I am still confuse, may be there are some urls in previous job's queue.